# Wordpress - Adding classes to categories in get_the_category_list

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am using `get_the_category_list()` to return the linked list of categories for a post. I would like to identify two (IDs 6 and 7 below) and give them classes.
I have used a filter to identify them;

```
add_filter('the_category_list', 'category_flags');


function category_flags($categories) {
  $category_flags = array (6, 7);
  if (!empty($categories) && is_array($categories)) {
    foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
      if (in_array($category->term_id, $category_flags)) {            
        $category->class = "flag";
        //var_dump ($category);
      }
    }
  }
  return $categories;
}
```

But that gets me no further as I can't find a filter for get_the_category_list.

How can I approach this problem without using a PHP replace (or is this sledgehammer the only way?)

Comment: Hope this post will be helpful for you https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/

Comment: you have to override the theme, where it displays the category

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use PHP's `preg_replace` function for inserting a class attribute just after the opening anchor tag? No rewriting of the function required.

```
$categories_list = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="my-class"', get_the_category_list( ', ' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer, my sledgehammer, was to rewrite `get_the_category_list()` thus;

```
function wp15022018_get_the_category_list( $separator = '', $parents = '', $post_id = false ) {

  global $wp_rewrite;

  $categories = apply_filters( 'the_category_list', get_the_category( $post_id ), $post_id );

  $rel = ( is_object( $wp_rewrite ) && $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) ? 'rel="category tag"' : 'rel="category"';

  $thelist = '';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
      if ( 0 < $i )
        $thelist .= $separator;
        $thelist .= '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . ' " class="'.$category->class. '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
      ++$i;
    }

  return  $thelist;
}
```

I use the filter in my original question to identify the categories of interest. My categories are flat so I've grossly simplified the function, though it's not necessary.

I've left this here as it seems to me there are many reasons why one might wish to modify the native category list output. I've not marked this as an answer as somebody clever might come up with a more simple method.